cannot post a route because of middleware
I am developing a project with Go. I wrote a middleware for this project and it works quite correctly. However, I don't want the middleware to be affected when a request is sent to the login route because I get a “Missing Authorization header” error. So I added this code in middleware:
if c.Path() == "/login" {
        return c.Next()
    }

When I add this, I get the error “404 cannot post /login”. What is the reason for this? My other codes are:
    container.Invoke(func(loginRoute *userroutes.LoginRoute) {
    if loginRoute == nil {
        return
    }

    app.Post("/login", loginRoute.Handler)
})

and
func BuildContainer() *dig.Container {
container := dig.New()
container.Provide(
    trait.NewLoginHandler,
)
return container

}

I cannot tell from the code above what router you are using and how the middleware is applied. But typically you do NOT apply the middleware on routes that don’t need it.

Okay, let's assume we never use middleware. I still get a 404 error. Could this be caused by the SetupRoutes function where I define the routes? What information should I share with you to help you more

Can you show a basic setup of the router? I see the tag for Go-Fiber, so assuming that is what you're using. Basically you can apply middleware to a single route or more. Or to the entire router. Fiber shows both examples: https://docs.gofiber.io/api/middleware/adaptor. It's the difference between app.Use(mw) or http.HandleFunc("/func", adaptor.FiberHandlerFunc(greet)) for a single route. And here is a simple demo of both with Gorilla mux: https://go.dev/play/p/TJah5Ggp3vH

404 means the app is handling routes but not that one as it’s being sent. Wrong method would likely be a 405. So maybe a conflict with the sequence of routes you have?

Can you please share a more comprehensive view of the code? The bits you shared are not enough to respond.

`func SetupRoutes(app *fiber.App, container *dig.Container) error {
app.Use(middlewares.AuthMiddleware())
container.Invoke(func(loginRoute *userroutes.LoginRoute) {
if loginRoute == nil {
return
}
app.Post("/login", loginRoute.Handler)
})
return nil
}`
and main.go
`app.Use(LoggerMiddleware)
container := di.BuildContainer()
if err := routes.SetupRoutes(app, container); err != nil {
panic(err)
}`

I do some changes and I get a error as *panic: userroutes.LoginRoute, missing dependencies for function "user-service/app".mustInvoke[...].func1 (/Users/utkukaragul/Desktop/orange-rabbit/backend/user-service/app/routes.go:24): missing type: trait.LoginHandler

Feel free to update the question above with the code. It will probably be easier for you to add code blocks, also easier to read.
